# I want to send Data(Image) from Nodejs to Python by using Socket?

Tags: python, node.js, sockets, http, websocket

In the following **Nodejs** Code I'm Receiving an image in the Base64 Format, and I want to send this Image to **Python** with socket.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);


app.use(express.static('public'));

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules'));

app.get('/', function(req, res,next) {
    console.log('loading...');
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index3.html');
});

server.listen(4200);

io.on('connection', function(client) {
    console.log('Client connected...');

    client.on('join', function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });


    client.on('matObj', function(data) {
        console.log("Img => "+data);
        // code to send image to python, data contain base64 image
    });
});
```

HTML code : I'm sending the image with socket.
I want to send same image to python with socket, If there is any other way to do this, like can I send image directly from HTML/JS to Python3 ?

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
        <div id="future"></div>


        <input type="button" value="image send" onclick="sendImg()">
        <img id="imgs" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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" alt="noload">

        <script src="/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>

        <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>

        <script src="image-to-base64/image-to-base64.min.js"> </script>

        <script>
        var socket = io.connect();

        socket.on('connect', function(data) {
          socket.emit('join', 'Hello World from client');
        });


        function sendImg(){
          myImg = document.getElementById('imgs').src;
          console.log(myImg);
          socket.emit('matObj', myImg);
        }



    </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you update the code to show what you've tried so far? The question seems to be based on the code that is missing.

Comment: I added the HTML code, I Haven't wrote any other code I just add that comment to understanding from where I want to send image to python.